# Create multiple graphs with button in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following shiny script

```
 library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  #This should trigger a default 100 hist
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  numericInput("n", "n", 50),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  randomVals <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    runif(input$n)
  })

  randomVals2 <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    runif(n = 100)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(randomVals())
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    hist(randomVals2())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This provides me with a button I can press to get a histogram. It works fine. However, I would also like to include another button next to it that gives a histogram with default n = 100 (just for learning purposes).

However the second button does not seem to work.

Any thoughts on what should be changed to trigger it?

Answer (score 1):

@PorkChop has correctly pointed out one bug in your code, which is the repeated IDs of both buttons. Also, your don't have `plot2` defined in your UI function.

However, I would like to comment that the functions defined is a bit redundant. In principle, both buttons should preform the same functionalities (generate random data and plot their histogram), with different size parameter.

The neatest way would be defining one function that does the full functionality required, and calling it with the specific parameters with each button:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go_hist", "Go"),
  actionButton("go_hist_100", "Go with 100"), #This should trigger a default 100 hist
  numericInput("n", "n", 50),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  plotHist = function(size){
    randomData = runif(size)
    output$plot = renderPlot(hist(randomData, main = paste("n =", size)))
  }
  observeEvent(input$go_hist, plotHist(input$n))
  observeEvent(input$go_hist_100, plotHist(100))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

With such functionalization, your code will be easier to read, debug and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You cant have multiple buttons with the same id please change button names

```
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  #This should trigger a default 100 hist
  actionButton("go1", "Go"),
```